# creating board for 8 queen in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a chess board for the 8 queen problem. The challenge is to let a user enter the queens' positions and tell them if that position wouldn't be allowed due to other queens. I only have the board so far

This is the code i have so far:

```
boardsize = input('Board size: ')

rows = [[0] * int(boardsize)]
rows = str(rows).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(',','')

for i in range(int(boardsize)):
    print(i + 1, rows)
```

this produces:

Board size: 8

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I can't see a way to enter a "Q" (to symbolise a queen) where i want to enter it. I will then reprint the board with a Q instead of one of the zeros and repeat this until 8 queens are placed or there is no space for another queen. It must be user controlled.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that instead of storing a whole grid, you just store the queen position in each row. This is because only one queen can exist in each row, so you know this will be enough to store any queen. It also actually makes your life a bit easier as you have direct pointers to queens (rather than having to iterate through the board to find the queens). You could use this to do something like this:

```
sample_positions = [0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, None, None]

def print_positions(positions):
    for ind, pos in enumerate(positions):
        row = ["_"] * len(positions)

        if pos is not None:
            row[pos] = "Q"

        print("{}: {}".format(ind, " ".join(row)))

x, y = map(int, input("Enter new queen position> ").split())

sample_positions[y] = x

print_positions(sample_positions)
```

This program runs like this:

```
Enter new queen position> 6 7
0: Q _ _ _ _ _ _ _
1: _ _ Q _ _ _ _ _
2: _ _ _ _ Q _ _ _
3: _ Q _ _ _ _ _ _
4: _ _ _ Q _ _ _ _
5: _ _ _ _ _ Q _ _
6: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
7: _ _ _ _ _ _ Q _
```

I've included an example of how you might take input (although you would want to write a validation function and apply that first. I've also replaced your printing functionality with something a little more Pythonic - generally, doing string operations on a repr of a list isn't a good idea. Also, for this example the input assumes both `x` and `y` are given as integers - you can change this to letters or whatever as appropriate. I've moved the whole thing to be a little more 0-based for simplicity of implementation - I'd recommend using something like an underscore for an empty cell, not an integer.

Presumably you're not *too* interested in performance. This program does build up an empty row for each row it goes through - with some funky generator chaining you could probably make this a couple of nanoseconds faster, but that would make this answer more complicated than it already is.

This is a modified excerpt from my [queens project](https://github.com/elterminad0r/queens). (disclaimer: I wrote it). Should you wish to refer to it for more on how the representation works or how you might validate a board in this model, feel free. Note that my project is different to yours- mine brute-forces all possible solutions and features no interactive input.

Answer (score 0):

Leave `rows` as a list, and just change the appropriate element. Don't do any conversion to string; just `print` the individual elements as needed.

Also, make `rows` actually contain multiple rows (right now you only set up a single row before the string conversion).